# Loop error leads to stack buffer overflow in C

Tags: c, stack-overflow

It is part of the assignment.

Basically, there should be "These are not Palindromes!" or "These are Palindromes!" coming out, but whenever I run it and input chars (though it compiles well), it always gets me an error: stack-buffer-overflow. I wonder if it is the loop problem within the `even_count` function.

```
This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 62) 'pali_array' (line 30) <== Memory access at offset 95 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow /home/Execise in C/3.10.c:92 in even_count
```

And the original question is :
Write a program that prompts a user for a phrase and tells whether it is a palindrome or not.And don't use any built-in-string-handling function like strlen()and strcmp().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int Check_Pali(char pali_array[30],int count);
void lower_conversion(char pali_array[30],int count);
int odd_count(char pali_array[30],int middle);
int even_count(char pali_array[30],int middle);

int main(void){
    char c;
    int flag;
    int count=0;
    char pali_array[30];
    int i;
    while((c=getchar()!='\n')){
        for(i=0;i<30;i++){
        //fill the array with getchar.
        pali_array[i]=c;
        count++;
        if(ispunct(pali_array[i])||isspace(pali_array[i])){
            i--;
            count--;
        }
        //putchar(pali_array[i]);
    }
    }

    flag=Check_Pali(pali_array,count);
    if(flag==1){
        printf("These are not Palindromes!\n");
        }
            else{
                printf("These are Palindromes!\n");
            }
}

int Check_Pali(char pali_array[30],int count){
    int middle;
    int flag;
    //Set all the letters to lower case.
    if(count%2==0){
        middle=(count)/2;
        flag=even_count(pali_array,middle);
        return flag;
    }else{
        middle=count/2;
        flag=odd_count(pali_array,middle);
        return flag;
    }
}
//Turn all the char into lower case.
void lower_conversion(char pali_array[30],int count){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        pali_array[i] = tolower(pali_array[i]);
    }
}
//when middle is an odd number.
int odd_count(char pali_array[30],int middle){
    int i;
    int flag=0;
    for(i=1;i<=middle;i++){
        if(pali_array[middle-i]!=pali_array[middle+i]){
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
//when middle is an even number.
int even_count(char pali_array[30],int middle){
    int i;
    int j=1;
    int flag=0;
    for(i=0;i<middle;i++){
        if((pali_array[middle+i])!=pali_array[middle-j+1]){
            flag=1;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

The program compiles right, but after I input any word, it just get

```
error:stack-buffer-overflow.
```

The compiler I am using is gcc, and the flags are:

```
cc -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -pedantic -Wvla -std=c99 -g3 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined
```

Comment: Please note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`** value. Which is rather important if you want to compare it to the `int` value `EOF` (which you really should do).

Comment: Oh, and `c=getchar()!='\n'` is equal to `c = (getchar() != '\n')`. The value of `c` won't be what you expect.

Comment: And why the loop `for(i=0;i<30;i++)` inside the reading loop, that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: As for the problem, use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. When and where does your array indexes go out of bounds?

Comment: Isn't it `stack-buffer-overflow` instead of `stack-suffer-overflow`?

Comment: It's easier to read your code if it is indented consistently — preferably in an orthodox [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) such as Allman (which I use) or a variant of 1TBS (which many people use).

Answer (score 3):

Adding
`printf("count:%d\n", count);`
To the beginning of `Check_Pali()` shows that for every letter, count goes up by 30.
So my guess is that because you put your for-loop in your while statement, your count goes up by 30 for every letter in your palindrome word.
And then you're trying to access parts of `paly_array[]` that are larger than intended.